# Javascript calculation for a data loop with no decimals

Tags: javascript, loops, rounding, tofixed

I am trying to calculate prices for a loop of elements :

```
function calculateBill(id,price)
{

    var t = document.getElementById('total').value;

    var qty = document.getElementById('qty_'+id).value;

    var total = qty * price;


    var tcost = Number(t) + Number(total);

    document.getElementById('total').value = tcost ;
}
```

My PHP loop is :

```
<form name="sendgoods.php" method="post">
                        <?php


                        unset($data2);
                        unset($result2);
                        for( $i2 = 0; $i2<count($r2); $i2++ )
                        {
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $r2[$i2]['veg_name']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $r2[$i2]['ret_price']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $r2[$i2]['mop']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $r2[$i2]['ret_margin']; ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" id = "qty_<?php echo $i2; ?>" name="qty_<?php echo $i2; ?>" onkeyup="calculateBill('<?php echo $i2; ?>','<?php echo round($r2[$i2]['ret_price'],2); ?>')"  />
                                <input type="hidden" name="veg_name_<?php echo $i2; ?>" value="<?php echo $r2[$i2]['veg_name']; ?>" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="rate_<?php echo $i2; ?>" value="<?php echo $r2[$i2]['avg_rate']; ?>" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="mop_<?php echo $i2; ?>" value="<?php echo $r2[$i2]['mop']; ?>" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="ws_price_<?php echo $i2; ?>" value="<?php echo round($r2[$i2]['ws_price'],2); ?>" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="ws_margin_<?php echo $i2; ?>" value="<?php echo $r2[$i2]['ws_margin']; ?>" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="ret_price_<?php echo $i2; ?>" value="<?php echo round($r2[$i2]['ret_price'],2); ?>" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="ret_margin_<?php echo $i2; ?>" value="<?php echo $r2[$i2]['ret_margin']; ?>" />

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </table>
                            <input type="hidden" name="customer_id" value="<?php echo $cid; ?>" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="dt" value="<?php echo $dt_str; ?>" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="customer_type" value="<?php echo $ctype_id; ?>" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="counter" value="<?php echo count($r2); ?>"  />
                            <input type="hidden" name="add_goods" value="1" />


                             <div class="we">

                <span class="dscnt">DISCOUNT - </span>
                 <input type="text" id="discount" name="discount"  onchange="calculateDiscount()" />

                <span class="billng_amnt">Total Billing amount - </span>
                <input type="text" id="total" readonly="readonly" />

            </div>

                            <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />

                        </form>
```

My problem is if I add `tcost .toFixed(0)` it calculates the round values of the total cost in each row. Suppose the values are 36,50.8 and 23.64. It calculates as 36 + 51 + 24 = 111. But I want the round value of total of each row, ie 36 + 50.8 + 23.64 = 110.44 which can rounds up as 110.00 . Can you suggest me how I can achieve this ?

UPDATE:
its like suppose you have 3 loops. In the first loop , total row value is 36, second loop the total row value is 50.8( so total value for now is 36 + 50.8 ) . third loop row value is 23.64 ( so total value is 36+50.8+23.64) . If I add toFixed(0) to the total, the addition will be like ( 36 + 51 + 24 ) = 111 . But client need the addition to be like 36 + 50.8 + 23.64 =  110.44 , now round value of this is 110.00 . Hope question is clear now

Comment: its in php file..`for loop`

Comment: Are rows in a php file too? I'm not sure how your'e mixing server side and client side, but you can add a variable into your function, add `tcost` to this on every iteration. After the loop, round the value of the variable and show it on the page. If this won't work, we'll need to see more code...

Answer (score 0):

use parseFloat

that is for 
    a = 30 
    b =  50.8 
    c =  23.64

```
value = parseFloat(a) + parseFloat(b) + parseFloat(c);
```

Comment: "`... I want the round value of total ...`", `parseFloat()` is not for rounding... :-(.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Reading your question is awfully confusing ... especially when you commented on it saying "its in the php file" ... I thought this is a javascript issue!?

Also your calculation is incorrect

```
30 + 50.8 + 23.64 = 104.44
```

And in javascript:

```
var total = Number(30) + Number(50.8) + Number(23.64);
alert(total.toFixed()) // gives you '104'
```

Hope that helps some what

Comment: I need to add the variable `total` for the next row also. So I nedd the individual rows without round but the final of all the row total in round value

Comment: Its for javascript. My client needs to calculate immediately the total values. So basically its a javascript question where loop of values are added.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to round the value. There are 3 functions in Math:

- Math.floor<sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FMath%2Ffloor)</sup>

  Math.ceil<sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FMath%2Fceil)</sup>:  Returns the smallest integer greater than or equal to a number.

  Math.round<sup>[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)</sup>: Returns the value of a number rounded to the nearest integer.

> But I want the round value of total of each row, ie 36 + 50.8 + 23.64
>   = 110.44 which can rounds up as 110.00

I think you need `Math.round` :

```
Math.round ( 110.44 ) //110
```